# javascript get characters between slashes

Tags: javascript, string

Can someone please help. I need to get the characters between two slashes e.g:

```
Car/Saloon/827365/1728374
```

I need to get the characters between the second and third slashes. i.e `827365`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `split()` method of the `String` prototype, passing in the slash as the separator string:

```js
const value = 'Car/Saloon/827365/1728374';
const parts = value.split('/');

// parts is now a string array, containing:
// [ "Car", "Saloon", "827365", "1728374" ]
// So you can get the requested part like this:

const interestingPart = parts[2];
```

It's also possible to achieve this as a one-liner:

```js
const interestingPart = value.split('/')[2];
```

Documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2):

This will simply alert 1728374, as you want

```
alert("Car/Saloon/827365/1728374".split('/')[3]);
```

or, a bit longer, but also more readable:

```
var str = "Car/Saloon/827365/1728374";
var exploded = str.split('/');
/**
* str[0] is Car
* str[1] is Saloon
* str[2] is 827365
* str[3] is 1728374
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `the_string.split('/')` - it gives you an array containing the substrings between the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str = 'Car/Saloon/827365/1728374';
var arr = str.split('/'); // returns array, iterate through it to get the required element
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to divide the string in four parts:

```
'Car/Saloon/827365/1728374'.split('/')[2]
```

Gives "827365"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the .split() function like this:

```
("Car/Saloon/827365/1728374").split("/")[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Car/Saloon/827365/1728374".split("/")[2]
"Car/Saloon/827365/1728374".split("/")[3]
```

How many you want you take it.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "Car/Saloon/827365/1728374";

var items = str.split("/");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
   alert(items[i]);
}
```

OR

```
var lastItem = items[items.length - 1]; // yeilds 1728374
```

OR

```
var lastItem1728374 = items[2];
```